# Are the downloads of this website the full code of ubuntu for that version?

Tags: 22.04, software-sources, source-code, websites, source-packages

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release/source/
If i download the six source iso i have all the ubuntu code for that version?

Comment: As I understood it, it was the source code to build the ISOs themselves, and not the source code for all Ubuntu binaries in the repositories (*that can be downloaded too from launchpad, or just using `apt source` anyway*)

Answer (score 3):

It says on the page:

> The source images contain the source code used to build Ubuntu.
>
> Some source package versions on this image may not match related
> binary images, depending on exactly when the images were built. You
> can always find every version of Ubuntu source packages on Launchpad,
> using URLs of the following form:
>
> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/SOURCE-PACKAGE-NAME/+publishinghistory
> (index)
> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/SOURCE-PACKAGE-NAME/VERSION
> (specific version)